# Need help with a trigger detecting related records and the use of addError with Trigger Contexts

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages

Apologies to ask this but I am struggling. I have begun writing a trigger that will handle the automatic-closing of cases under certain conditions.  I have got bits and pieces working well but I am struggling with one piece of logic, it "should" detect if there are any open related WorkOrder(s) and if there is then it will display an error message to the user on the case page (where the trigger was initiated - after a user has updated the status to "closed").

Within the trigger I have this:

```
        if(Trigger.isBefore)
    {
        handler.OnBeforeUpdate(trigger.New ,trigger.Old,Trigger.NewMap,Trigger.OldMap);
    }
```

Within the Trigger Handler Class I have this:

```
    public void OnBeforeUpdate( List<Case> newCase, List<Case> oldCase, Map<ID, Case> newCaseMap , Map<ID, Case> oldCaseMap )
{
    system.debug('Case Trigger On Before Update ');
    caseActions.closeCase(oldCase);

}
```

And finally I have a CaseAction method that includes this:

```
    public static void closeCase(List<case> oldCase){

    Integer varValidateCount = 0;        
    List <WorkOrder> woList = new List<WorkOrder>(); 
    for (Case c: oldCase){
        for (WorkOrder wo: [SELECT id, isClosed FROM WorkOrder WHERE CaseId = :c.Id]){
            if (wo.isClosed != TRUE){
                varValidateCount++;
            }
        }
        if (varValidateCount > 0){
            //Can't figure out how to addError Here.
        }
    }
    if (varValidateCount == 0){
        /*update the case to closed*/
    }

}
```

All of this saves fine but when I try and close a case an error is reported stating:

> System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors:

I am 100% certain this is because i am trying to use it outside of the trigger context but could anyone advise best practice to change my code?  I am also, as I am learning, trying to ensure it is bulkified - is it OK to use SOQL in the for loop like above (I am conscious within the for Loop I shouldn't initiate any DML/SOQL statements)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are trying to add error in Trigger.old instead you need to add this in trigger.new

So you need to update your code

```
if (varValidateCount > 0){
    newCaseMap.get(c.Id).addError('Your message');
}
```

and use `Trigger.newMap`